# What image compression/quality is most efficient for iOS / Firebase Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage, image-compression

I'm working in Xcode and have an iOS app connected to Firebase. I'm currently uploading photos to Firebase Storage using the below code. It's working fine, but sometimes the pictures take a few seconds too download. I'm wondering if there's a better way to download/upload images? I'm thinking the images I'm using may be much larger than ever needed on an iPhone?

My current code includes:
1. upload compression quality 0.8
2. download max size: 27 * 1024 * 1024

```
//IMAGE UPLOAD CODE SNIPPET         
if let uploadImageData = photo.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
                let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
                photoStorageRefFull.putData(uploadImageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, err) in
                    //IF ERROR
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err)
                        print("PHOTO ERROR")
                    } else {
                        //IF NO ERROR
                        print("photo success!")
                        counter = counter + 1
                        dispatch.leave()
                    }
                }
            }
```

```
//IMAGE DOWNLOAD CODE SNIPPET
                let pathRef = DataService.instance.REF_STOR.reference(withPath: "\(userPhotoPath)/1.jpg")
                pathRef.getData(maxSize: 27 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error getting user photo.")
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        print("Successful get user photo!")
                        let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)
                        let userInfo = User(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: "n/a", age: age, gender: gender, currentCity: currentCity, provider: provider, userID: userID, userPhoto: userPhoto!)
                        handler(userInfo)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: 27 MB of data takes a few seconds to download from a mobile device? How is that a problem?

Comment: I'm wondering if 27MB is more than I actually need to show an image on an iPhone? A few seconds is fine, but certain functions download many pictures at once... which makes the seconds add up. Is there a smaller number I could be using that won't materially affect image quality when only viewing on an iPhone?

Comment: It depends on your tolerance for image quality.  You'll have to experiment with it to see what suits your requirements.

Comment: While this is not a bad question, the use case is unclear. Why would you want to download a 27Mb file to view on an iPhone (or any) screen? What's the user doing with it? One situation is where a user selects a photo for editing and then wants to zoom in/edit etc. In that case, it would only need to be downloaded at that time - prior to that thumbnails are an appropriate option. This is similar to photos stored in iCloud. Can you expand the use case a bit?

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for reaching out. It's for user profiles on the app. There is no photo editing and the maximum size of the image is about the width of the iPhone. Should I be using a smaller file size?

Comment: When responding to a comment, put an @ in front of the person name like this @purebreadd. If there's no editing and no zooming then you can use a much smaller image. The iPhone Xs Max has a rendered pixel resolution of 1242 x 2688 and if it's not taking up the full screen then it could be smaller than that. You can use 458 Pixels Per Inch if you want to get an idea of displayed size.

Comment: @Jay got it. Thanks!